# Install Git on CentOS 5.5

Tags: centos, yum, cpanel

I have added EPEL repo and here goes...

```
# yum install git-core
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: mirror.team-cymru.org
 * base: yum.singlehop.com
 * epel: mirrors.servercentral.net
 * extras: mirror.steadfast.net
 * rpmforge: fr2.rpmfind.net
 * updates: pubmirrors.reflected.net
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git.i386 0:1.7.3-1.el4.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.3-1.el4.rf for package: git
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.4 for package: git
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DBI) for package: git
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.4 for package: git
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Git) for package: git
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git.i386 0:1.7.3-1.el4.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.3-1.el4.rf for package: git
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DBI) for package: git
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Git) for package: git
---> Package openssl097a.i386 0:0.9.7a-9.el5_4.2 set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
git-1.7.3-1.el4.rf.i386 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(DBI) is needed by package git-1.7.3-1.el4.rf.i386 (rpmforge)
git-1.7.3-1.el4.rf.i386 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(Git) is needed by package git-1.7.3-1.el4.rf.i386 (rpmforge)
git-1.7.3-1.el4.rf.i386 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.3-1.el4.rf is needed by package git-1.7.3-1.el4.rf.i386 (rpmforge)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(DBI) is needed by package git-1.7.3-1.el4.rf.i386 (rpmforge)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(Git) is needed by package git-1.7.3-1.el4.rf.i386 (rpmforge)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.3-1.el4.rf is needed by package git-1.7.3-1.el4.rf.i386 (rpmforge)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

But...

```
# yum install perl-DBI
No package perl-DBI available.
Nothing to do
```

Any idea?

Comment: As perl-DBI is in the base repo you should use another base mirror. it seems yum.singlehop.com has no base packages. And this is not git or perl related.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So,

I was recently setting up a cpanel instance on this server, and I was pretty surprised as I have installed git without issue before on CentOS boxes before.

So cpanel has blocked all perl packages from being installed or updated because they don’t want updates to break or conflict with their packages. Thankfully yum provides a nice one time workaround for this kind of situation.

> yum --disableexcludes=main install git

Comment: This works, and it looks like CPanel is still working just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your basic problem here is that you're mixing the RPMforge and EPEL add-on repos. As you see, they're not always compatible. Pick one and use that.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the perl* from your /etc/yum.conf file..then rerun your yum install.

Make sure you remember to put it back in the conf file after you've installed git
or some subsequent update may clobber something cpanel needs.